# how to change android webview context menu(open, open inOpen in new window, bookmark link ...)?

Tags: android

When, I used long press on any web link(URL) on web page, Android will display the Context menu with actions (Open, Open in new window, bookmark link, save link, share link, …. ). As per my under stand these options are provided by the Android.

How can I customize the above context menu and add one more action to the Context menu?